# Visual studio intellisense / syntax highlighting not working for remote files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

I recently had to reinstall windows 10 on my laptop, and all applications. I have been using visual studio 2017 fine for months and months, but post install I cant seem to get code highlighting / intellisense working for remote files accessed over our VPN. Previously it would sometimes take a little time for the highlighting etc to be shown and I could often force it to pick it up using ctrl-k ctrl-d. Now it no longer seems to work at all. Im working with c# asp.net files.

If i copy the file's locally then it works, but obviously i lose the link to all references that are on the server by default. I've tried removing settings files and such, and even tried going back to visual studio 2015 which also used to work for me but to no avail. Someone else must be having these same issues?

Comment: Tested on another machine on the same network, using the same vpn client accessing the same files and it works so something specific to the machine's settings.

Comment: Ok, looks like its finding an issue with an assembly on the server and quitting... The server is operating normally and not having this issue, and the other instance of visual studio is not having the issue either.

ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Aurigma.GraphicsMill.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so ive now solved this. VC++ runtime files needed installing locally for one of the assemblys on the server.

Further update :

I've had similar issues again after a recent reinstall, and this time I needed to make sure the correct .net Framework SDK / targeting packs were installed to match the target framework on the remote server.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, please mark it as answer and that will help other community members who meet the same issue to easier search this helpful information.